# Memory Leak When Handling CGMutablePath

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a memory leak when working with a `CGMutablePath` under the following circumstances:

```
- (CGMutablePathRef) textMutablePathForFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(frame.size.width / self.shapeMutablePathSize.width, frame.size.height / self.shapeMutablePathSize.height);

    return CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(self.shapeMutablePath, &transform);
}

- (CTFrameRef) textFrameForFrame:(CGRect)frame framesetter:(CTFramesetterRef)framesetter
{
    CGMutablePathRef textMutablePath = [self textMutablePathForFrame:frame];
    CTFrameRef textFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), textMutablePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(textMutablePath);

    return textFrame;
}
```

Through instrument analysis I get a memory leak at the line with "`return`" in `textMutablePathForFrame` that says "Potential leak of an object allocated on line 132" (line 132 is the return line itself).

I also get a memory leak in `textFrameForFrame` at the line "`CGPathRelease(textMutablePath);`" that says: "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller".

Can't wrap my head around this, felt like I was finally getting a good understanding of memory management in Core.

UPDATE: Looking like this is possibly a bug, going to bump it one more time to see if anyone else feels differently.

Comment: Do you `CFRelease()` the returned objects from the calling function?

Comment: @H2CO3 - yeah I just checked and in all instances when I'm calling textMutablePathForFrame, I usually store it in a local CTFrontRef, then I set a property to that local CTFontRef, then I release the local CTFontRef.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Think it's a bug maybe?

Comment: Note comment below. The analyzer is correct; this is not a bug. The name should be `newMutablePathForFrame`.

Comment: @RobNapier - Thanks Rob, that worked and I'm shocked, never would've figured that out. Do you want to put it as an answer? Also, I was wondering, do you do consulting for the iPhone, particularly in the area of CoreText? I have your book, and was looking for your contact information but couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes; my address is robnapier@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JonathanCichon is correct in principle, but has the wrong naming convention. The correct naming convention for the ObjC method is `newMutablePathForFrame`. The analyzer is correct. The "Create" rule only applies to Core Foundation. The ObjC naming conventions are in the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). The Core Foundation rules, which are slightly different and include the "Create" rule, are in the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you have a memory leak, change your `textMutablePathForFrame` method-name to `createMutablePathForFrame` and the warnings should disapear.

Comment: Jon that is just a naming convention, changing the name of my method won't accomplish anything.

Comment: @CoDEFRo Do you CFRelease() the returned objects from the caller?

Comment: the analyzer uses naming conventions to print warnings or not. As you clearly creating - and returning - a new object in your method, xcode assumes there is a memory leak. Also xcode assumes you are releasing a object you dont own with `CGPathRelease(textMutablePath)`. To give xcode a hint on what you are doing, you have to follow naming-conventions, or just ignore the warning.

Comment: looks like naming conventions only work with coreFoundation not with objective-c. Two solutions to get rid of the warnings: write a c-function and use self as second parameter `CGMutablePathRef createMutablePathForFrame(CGRect path, YourClass self)` or wrap the path in a `UIBezierPath` so it will be handled bei ARC/Autorelease.

Comment: @JonathanCichon - So it sounds like you think this is a bug on Apple's part? BTW thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes i think the Analyzer does something wrong. You could write a loop with many iterations and check in instruments for leaks, but im sure this two functions are fine.

Comment: @JonathanCichon is correct in principle, but has the wrong naming convention. The correct naming convention for the ObjC method is `newMutablePathForFrame`. The analyzer is correct. The "Create" rule only applies to Core Foundation. The ObjC naming conventions are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html.